# When is document ready needed and when not in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am not sure when we use `$(document).ready(function() { });` and when we can declare a `$(function() { }` without it being declared in the `$(document).ready(function() { });`

For example the following snippet:

```
<body>  
    <textarea id="test" cols="50" rows="15"><p><h3>Test H3</h3>This is some sample text to test out the <b>WYSIWYG Control</b>.</p></textarea>  
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        $(function() {  
            $("textarea").htmlarea();  
        });  
</script>
```

works without using the `$(document).ready(function() { });` but the following:

```
<body>  
    <textarea id="test" cols="50" rows="15"><p><h3>Test H3</h3>This is some sample text to test out the <b>WYSIWYG Control</b>.</p></textarea>  
    <script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("btn").click(function(){
            alert('Hello!!!');
        });
    });

        $(function() {  
            $("textarea").htmlarea();  
        });  
</script>
```

When I press the button with `id="btn"`, it does nothing.
Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 6):

In the second example, assuming you actually do have a button with an `id` of `btn` somewhere, the problem is that you’re missing a `#` to select by ID:

```
// ⌄ here
$("#btn")
```

Calling `$` with one function and calling `$(document).ready` with that same function [are equivalent](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

To answer the question of “when do I need to wait for `ready`”, though, the answer’s simply that you need to wait until an element exists in the DOM to be able to find it. Sometimes, that takes waiting until the entire page (though not necessarily all of its linked resources) has been downloaded and parsed into a tree; sometimes you’ve included your script at some point after the element that you need, and so you don’t have to wait at all; sometimes you use event delegation on elements that exist (a common example of which would be the entire document). You could almost say it’s up to preference.

Answer (score 2):

You should always be using the `$(document).ready(function(){})` to bootstrap your application really unless there is a specific need not to use it as they will get executed once the DOM is ready to be traversed.

In your examples however your two functions do the same thing, I prefer to use `$(document).ready()` because it is more explicit and readable.

The reason your code is not working is because you have not used the correct selector using $("btn") will look for html elements e.g.  but won't find any because it's invalid html. You should use `$("#btn")` to select your button. the '#' is used to find id's whilst the '.' can be used to select multiple items with a specific class attribute.

Comment: +1 for stressing the importance of putting bootstrapping code in `$(document).ready()`.

Answer (score 1):

If your button has *id* `btn`, you should use `$('#btn')` selector, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        alert('Hello!!!');
    });
});
```

---

To the first question:

There is **no difference** between `$(document).ready(function () { ... })` and `$(function() { ... })`, you can use any of those.

Comment: So `$(document).ready` is redundant?

Comment: It's not *redundant*, but you can use _either_ `$(document).ready(function () { ... })` _or_ `$(function() { ... })`.

Answer (score 0):

Functions declared in `document.ready` events get executed when the dom is ready. Other functions, (outside `document.ready`) is invoked when the corresponding event is fired.

Comment: `invoked when the corresponding event is fired.` but this implies that the dom is ready right?

Answer (score 0):

There are two events that matter when you want things to happen "early" in a web page:

- The DOM is constructed in browser memory. When this is done, `$(document).ready` fires.
- All the resources--images, stylesheets, video, scripts, etc--have been downloaded. This is the `onload` event.

If you aren't fetching anything (or nothing too big) over the wire, it is quite possible that both events are all but simultaneous, and you can simply run something in the `script` tag at the bottom of the page to do work.

Note also that the two approaches you took are equivalent. They both are "ready" event handlers.

Having said all that, none of it is relevant to your issue. `$("btn")` won't resolve to anything because your selector is bad. There is no element called button. You probably meant an id of `btn`, in which case you want to do this `$("#btn")`